# Showing a polynomial is irreducible over an extension field.

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Show that the polynomial

$$ x^3 - 3$$ Is irreducible over

$$ Q(i, \sqrt2 ) $$

I'm a little stuck as I don't think I can use Eisenstein's criterion as we're not over the rationals.  Also I know that the roots of the polynomial are $ \sqrt[3] 3 $ followed by $\omega \sqrt[3] 3 $ and $\omega^2 \sqrt[3] 3 $ 
However I don't really know how to use this imformation to prove the polynomial is irreducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a polynomial of degree 3 or less is reducible, it means it has a linear factor in $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt2)[x]$. Does this help you?

Comment: So it will have a factor of the form $ (x-r) $  where $ r=i , \sqrt2 $  ?

Comment: @Padraic If you assume it's reducible, then $r\in\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt2)$. So if you prove that $\sqrt[3]3,\omega\sqrt[3]3,\omega^2\sqrt[3]3\not\in \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt2)$, you are done.

Comment: You beauty! That I can do. Thank you!