# Prove that $x^3 -2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to prove what the tittle says. So far i know that $\sqrt[3]{2} \not \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and that $\{1,\sqrt{5} \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$. I have tried to write $$x^3 -2=m(x)q(x)$$  With $m,q \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})[x]$ and express the coefficients of $m $ and $q$ as a linear combination of the basis in an attempt to get a contradiction but in the last step it gets quite messy and so i think tha way is not going to have result.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I will start by computing $(a+\sqrt{5}b)^3-2$ for $a, b\in\mathbb{Q},$ and look which one makes it zero, if possible.

Comment: Some more solved examples: N.S. gave you an answer for the degree $3$, it is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/699090/399263, here is some strategy for degree $4$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2693165/399263

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

If
$$x^3 -2=m(x)q(x)
$$
with non-constant $m,q$,
then one of $m,q$ must be linear and hence must have a root in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. This root is a root of $x^3-2$.

Comment: Wow this solution is quite simple and fancy. Thanks a lot. Just for the record: This would give, after a few calculations, that $\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, right ?

Comment: @DonaldW.Johnson Observe that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \subset \mathbb R$ which implies that the root would be real, and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is the only real root of $x^3-2$. This gives indeed that $\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$