# Is there an algorithm to check if a polynomial with integer coefficients is reducible over some extension of $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I have been reading some solved questions here, for example:

[Showing a polynomial is irreducible over an extension field.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699090/showing-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-over-an-extension-field?rq=1)

[Is $f(y) = 5 - 4y^2 + y^4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693165/is-fy-5-4y2-y4-irreducible-over-mathbbq-sqrt5?rq=1)

showing how certain polynomials, of degree 3, 4 and 5, are irreducible over some respective extensions of $\mathbb Q$ which are proper in $\mathbb R$. But it seems that every answer uses a different method or approach, or that these polynomials have special features allowing them to be checked. Hence my question.

One can also ask how would you come up with a question like that? How to make sure that some polynomial can in fact be verified to be irreducible over some field $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ for this irrational $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Maybe start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_over_algebraic_extensions_(Trager's_method) and Trager's paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800205.806338

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a factorization algorithm, as an inspiration I suggest to look at what computer algebra systems use. For example, PARI/GP has a function [`nffactor`](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/General_number_fields.html#se:nffactor) for factorization of univariate polynomial over given number field. Per documentation it implements Belabas's variant of van Hoeij's algorithm, so you can check the corresponding article [A relative van Hoeij algorithm over number fields](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717103001561) by Karim Belabas. I suspect other systems use same or similar algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can try looking for [rational root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and [Eisenstein’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) criterion. I only know two such as Kronecker's method and the Zassenhaus algorithm but they only workout with full factorisation.

Comment: The first two do not provide an algorithm for testing irreducibility. If you find a rational root, and the polynomial is of degree greater than 1, then it is reducible. And if you don't... then what? If you can find a prime $p$ such that the polynomial is Eisenstein at $p$, then it is irreducible. And if you don't find such a prime... then what?